# Fetching records from DynamoDB using QuerySpec

Tags: java, database, amazon-web-services, datatable, amazon-dynamodb

In a DynamoDB table where CustomerStatus is a column in which item may contain 'Active','Inactive' or 'Deleted' as CustomerStatus. I want to fetch all customers whose status is 'Active' as well 'Inactive'. 
Here is the code sample I am using, but I am not sure how to get it done.

```
private Object data(MuleEventContext eventContext) {
    List<Object> finalJson = new ArrayList<Object>();


        String tableName = "Customers";

        NameMap nameMap = new NameMap();
        nameMap.put("#v_status", "CustomerStatus");
        ValueMap valueMap = new ValueMap();
        valueMap.put(":v_statusval", "Deleted");
        BasicAWSCredentials cre = new BasicAWSCredentials(accesKey,secretKey);
        AmazonDynamoDB dynamoDB1 = AmazonDynamoDBClientBuilder.standard()
                .withCredentials(new AWSStaticCredentialsProvider(cre)).withRegion(Regions.EU_WEST_1).build();
        DynamoDB dynamoDB = new DynamoDB(dynamoDB1);
        Table table = dynamoDB.getTable(tableName);


        QuerySpec querySpec = new QuerySpec().withKeyConditionExpression("#v_status != :v_statusval")
            .withNameMap(nameMap)
            .withValueMap(valueMap);



         ItemCollection<QueryOutcome> items = null;
         Iterator<Item> iterator = null;
         Item item = null;

    try {               
            items = table.query(querySpec);
            iterator = items.iterator();                
            while (iterator.hasNext()) {
                item = iterator.next();
                finalJson.add(item.asMap());
            }

    } catch (Exception e) {
        logger.info(e.getMessage());
    }


    return finalJson;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can't filter on a HASH key.

I would need to know which attribute is the HASH key and which is the RANGE key.

If the *CustomerStatus* is not the HASH key, the best way is to create a secondary index for this attribute and do 2 different queries:

- One for the *Active*;
- Another one for the *Inactive*.

This is the most efficient way to do this kind of query.

Another way is doing a scan and **filtering** the attribute, using the `IN` operand, as stated in [Syntax for Condition Expressions](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/amazondynamodb/latest/developerguide/Expressions.OperatorsAndFunctions.html#Expressions.OperatorsAndFunctions.Syntax). But this will read all data from your table, can be slow, and consume a lot capacity.

Comment: The table contains data in JSON format.  Like `{
   "CustomerName":"Alex Parker",
   "CustomerDescription":"Retailer",
   "CustomerStatus":"Active",
   "profileID":"CUST001"
}` the customerStatus maybe 'active','inactive','expired' and 'deleted'. I want to fetch all the items in table where customerStatus is not 'deleted'